# Postresql get the same fileno row and count more than one

Tags: postgresql-8.3

Table_name

```
pno,pyr,cname,pname
1,2008,X,Y
1,2008,X,Z
2,2009,A,Y
```

If cname or pname count more than 1

How can I get the result like this

```
1,2008,X
1,2008,X
```

Comment: Are you **really** using Postgres **8.3**?

Comment: What if there is a row `3,2010,W,Y` should that be included as well? (Because pname = Y appears twice)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes